Valid regional time format produces invalid display in command line and taskbar
I am using windows 11 with german locale, build 26100.2454. In regional settings, my short time format is set to HH:mm' Uhr', which is a proposed value in the time format combo box.
Unfortunately, if I use the windows terminal command dir, the time is displayed in the wrong format 23:55 11r instead of 23:55 Uhr:

If I enable the new "abbreviated date and time in taskbar" option, the same behaviour can be observed there:

Why is this my time format behaving this way?

I don't know why, but it looks as if the literal text uhr is interpreted as a time format specifier, where h is the hour on a twelve hour clock, and r is untranslated (no idea where U went, though). Maybe you could try double quotes rather than single, or remove the space character? I don't have a PC around here, so can't test myself.

I tried to use double quotes, but windows then displays an error message that I entered an invalid time format.
